# Maintaining session on my Codeigniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am having two domain urls for my online store:

example1.com for admin,

and example2.com for front end.

My CI project on both the URLs access the same database.

So, the problem now is when I stay in the admin side, everything works fine. But if I visit the front end site once and then come back to admin url and reload, then my session is destroyed and I have to login again.

If any one can explain me why the session is being destroyed.

So, I want a solution here to access the same database in different urls in codeigniter with out destroying the session.

Comment: You can store session in database and check.

Comment: sessions are being stored in ci_sessions and getting destroyed when I reload the frontend website

Comment: Seems to me the problem is your front end sessions are overwriting your back end sessions and vice versa. Most likely because the session in the DB are based on your IP if I remember correctly.

Comment: @KiranKumarDash can you show us how you set your session when login? Also show some code so we can help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CI application config file, make 'sess_use_database' to true, so that session will store in database, which makes session intact on different domains.